# Is it recommended to keep all scenarios response data into external files and reading inside of code instead feature files?

Tags: rest, cucumber, karate

Please help me understand the best usage of BDD and feature files.

I have Rest calls and need to validate response data. Can I give expected response data from feature file as mentioned below?

```
Then response includes the following in any order:

| data[].username           | 1111 |
   | data[].phoneNumbers[].phoneNumber                  | 122-222-2222        |
| data[].retailLocationRoles[*].securityRoleId | 10 |
```

Otherwise should I keep expected response data (table data as mentioned above) in external files and reading inside of code? Is this a best practice ?

If expected response data changes in the future, is it a good idea to change inside feature files? Or do we need to follow TDD process?

Some one suggested to me to keep data in external files rather than feature files and read external file data inside of code, and saying it's not a good idea to change feature file when response data changes.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally up to you. If you read from external files, you can re-use them in multiple features. If you don't need to re-use, keep them in-line. And please don't worry about "BDD" you can [ignore it](https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39).

One more advantage of keeping JSON files external is that you can open them in a JSON editor.

Don't over-think your tests, just get started and you can easily evolve later once you understand the concepts.

Since you seem to be looking only for specific items, a normal match should be sufficient:

```
* def response = { data: [ { username: '1111', phoneNumbers: [ '122-222-2222' ], retailLocationRoles: [ { securityRoleId: 10 } ] } ] }

* def phone = '122-222-2222'
* def role = { securityRoleId: 10 }
* def user = { username: '1111', phoneNumbers: '#(^phone)', retailLocationRoles: '#(^role)' }

* match response.data contains user
```

If you want you can re-use the `user` object above, by a `call` to a JS file or a feature file.

Comment: Thanks peter for your reply, response data if I keep it in external files, not sure which data comes for which call. Just think in case, we have scenario out line for multiple user data how to manage in external files . in case of 200 scenarios with different data , if scenarios fails randomly.  Just think about memory point of view each scenario will load entire file to read particular data... if our tests runs parallel how much memory will be occupied in RAM.

Comment: I believe we can keep input data in json files because when we same input body for multiple post calls.

Comment: @krishna01012002 explore karate it has multiple ways to approach this. you can do it :)

Comment: Thanks Peter for your help :)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, I hope you understan my question, What I understood from you, we have to create JSON files For example: User Response as one Json file and data should be passed from fature file like in JAVA as creating pojo classes, Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @krishna01012002 yes. please please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

Comment: Thanks Peter , I have gone through example . Scenario: using json from a file
    * table employees
        | firstName | lastName |
        | 'John'    | 'Smith'  |
        | 'Jane'    | 'Doe'    |
    Given request ({ employees: employees })
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match $ == read('sample.json') , 
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }
  ]
},

Comment: in above example, if user detail changes then again we need to write one more sample.json file with new data, if I have 100 users then .. :(

Comment: @krishna01012002 unless you read all the docs it is hard to help you. hint: look for "embedded expressions", you can use 1 JSON for 100 different users, there are many ways. I am stopping here, maybe others will have patience to help you - all the best :)

Comment: Thanks Peter for your patience, You gave me good inputs with patience.

Comment: some one suggesting below approach in my team. So thought of taking experts advice   ,  Kindly go through below link , I hope you will understand their ideas. They are asking me to keep all data in csv files instead in feature files. Thanks for your great help.

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/api-testing-framework-using-bdd-approach-through-cucumber-and-rest-assured/

Comment: @krishna01012002 hope you read this and realize the right thing to do :) https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39 - and karate supports CSV if you really want, search for it in the docs

Comment: def response = { data: [ { username: '1111', phoneNumbers: [ '122-222-2222' ], retailLocationRoles: [ { securityRoleId: 10 } ] } ] }

* def phone = '122-222-2222'
* def role = { securityRoleId: 10 }
* def user = { username: '1111', phoneNumbers: '#(^phone)', retailLocationRoles: '#(^role)' } . above response data can I keep it in CSV then how can I match plz,  Reading CSV file requestbody(payload) not about response body.

Comment: Please go through this link and let me know how this is possible with Karate. https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/api-testing-framework-using-bdd-approach-through-cucumber-and-rest-assured/

Comment: I went through all Karate docs.  could not find .. Reading csv file is easy but mapping response data with csv is the challenge. Kindly refer my link , you will understand what I am expecting.

Comment: @krishna01012002 if you "went through all Karate docs" and did not find the answer - then karate is not the right choice for you. sorry :)